# Trying to add Applied Energistics api through build.gradle

Tags: gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am starting on a minecraft mod, but I cannot get the build.gradle right.

I wanted to create a mod **on top of applied energistics** but I cannot get it to build when I add this **mod as a gradle dependency**. I looked all the dependencies up on an other repository, **but when I build it gives errors like below, and some other errors on the general minecraft code base**

```
Error:(3, 26) java: package net.minecraft.init does not exist
```

This is the code I have right now:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url = "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.3-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle.forge'
//Only edit below this line, the above code adds and enables the necessary things for Forge to be setup.

version = mod_version + "-" + mod_channel
group = mod_group
archivesBaseName = mod_basename

sourceCompatibility = targetCompatibility = '1.8' // Need this here so eclipse task generates correctly.
compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = targetCompatibility = '1.8'
}

minecraft {
    version = minecraft_version + "-" + forge_version

    replaceIn "package-info.java"

    replace "@version@", project.version
    replace "@modversion@", mod_version
    replace "@modchannel@", mod_channel

    // used when launching minecraft in dev env
    mappings = mcp_mappings
}

repositories {
    maven {
        name 'Mobius Repo'
        url "http://mobiusstrip.eu/maven"
    }
    maven {
        name = "JEI repo"
        url "http://dvs1.progwml6.com/files/maven"
    }
}

dependencies {
    // installable runtime dependencies
    compileOnly "mcp.mobius.waila:Hwyla:${hwyla_version}"

    // compile against provided APIs
    compileOnly "mezz.jei:jei_${minecraft_version}:${jei_version}:api"
    compileOnly "mcp.mobius.waila:Hwyla:${hwyla_version}"

    // at runtime, use the full JEI jar
    runtime "mezz.jei:jei_${minecraft_version}:${jei_version}"

    deobfCompile "appeng:appliedenergistics2:${ae_verion}"
}

processResources {
    // this will ensure that this task is redone when the versions change.
    inputs.property "version", project.version
    inputs.property "mcversion", project.minecraft.version
    // replace stuff in mcmod.info, nothing else
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        include 'mcmod.info'

        // replace version and mcversion
        expand 'version':project.version, 'mcversion':project.minecraft.version
    }

    // copy everything else except the mcmod.info
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        exclude 'mcmod.info'
    }
}
```

The version that I am trying to add is:

```
ae_verion=rv5-stable-8
```

Comment: SO's [minecraft] tag is pretty slow. I unfortunately don't know what's going on, but if you ask over on the [Forge forums](http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/forum/70-modder-support/) I'm sure those more familiar with adding dependencies will be able to help.

Comment: @Draco18s Ok I will do that :) thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add 'api' at the end of the compile argument (used to be 'dev'). Also, iirc adding transitive=false solves dependency issues.

```
dependencies {
    compile ("appeng:appliedenergistics2:${ae_version}:api") {
        transitive = false
    }
}
```